# Split string and integer in Pandas series - Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, series

I have one column in a Pandas dataframe with "title of the movie" and "Year" (ex.  "Toy Story (1995)") all in the same string.
I have to split them in 2 different columns and of course the year must be an integer.
I tried with this method (below) but the year remains a "object" type because it has parenthesis.
Also, it doesn't work for one movie (there's still a title)...

```
split_movie = movies["Movie"].str.rsplit(" ", n = 1, expand=True)
movies["Movie Title"] = split_movie[0]
movies["Movie Year"] = split_movie[1]
```

I don't know if I can use the pd.year method or if I have to split the string in Python by creating a list...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping closer to your original code...

**Try:**

```
movies[['Title', 'Year']] = movies["Movie"].str.rsplit("(", n=1, expand=True)
movies['Year'] = movies['Year'].str.replace(')', '', regex=False)
movies['Year'] = movies['Year'].astype('int64')
print(movies.info())
```

**Outputs:**

```
 #   Column   Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------   --------------  ----- 
 0   Movie    15 non-null     object 
 1   Title    15 non-null     object
 2   Year     15 non-null     int64
```

Comment: Can I ask you why we shall use regex? I just never used it before...

Comment: The answer above does not use regex (note: `regex=False`).  I thought I would avoid using regex for the example above and show something closer to what you were trying to do in the question with `split_movie[0]`.  You can definitely use regex and it could do the extraction in one line, but it can be harder to understand the answer if you are just beginning to look at pandas and, as you said, if you have never used it before it is another thing to learn.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry, I formulated the question wrongly. I meant what are we doing by setting regex=False. I googled it a bit and didn't understand what it is used for...If you can provide me an explanation I would appreciate it a lot :)

Comment: Np.  If you are looking for a plain text substring in a column you set it to `False` with a capital `F`.  If you want to use a regex pattern (that is more complex but can be powerful) you set it to `True` - with a capital `T`.  See the 'Parameters' list near the top of [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Comment: You could take your original dataframe and run `movies['Title'] = movies['Movie'].str.replace(r'\s*(.*\S)\s*\((\d{4})\)', r'\1', regex=True)` and then `movies['Year'] = movies['Movie'].str.replace(r'\s*(.*\S)\s*\((\d{4})\)', r'\2', regex=True)` and then `movies['Year'] = movies['Year'].astype('int64')` - notice the `regex` parameter is now set to `regex=True`.  To see the regex in action use a [site like regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/RyiWkI/1) and copy in the regex and part of your dataset and note the coloured matched groups.

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.extractall`:

```
>>> df.join(df['Movie'].str.extractall(r'\s*(.*\S)\s*\((\d{4})\)') \
                       .rename(columns={0: 'Movie Title', 1: 'Movie Year'}) \
                       .reset_index(drop=True))

              Movie Movie Title Movie Year
0  Toy Story (1995)   Toy Story       1995
```

*Regular expression was enhanced by @Bill.*

Comment: Minor improvement to drop whitespace around title: use `'\s*(.*\S)\s*\((\d{4})\)'`